# where do I put "/usr/bin/eGTouchD" to run after x server is started?

Tags: 12.04

I have a netbook (samsung n145) with an egalax touch screen. The egalax driver install recommends adding "/usr/bin/eGTouchD" to /etc/gdm/default immediately prior to the exit statement. This does not start the daemon.

btw: the driver installer puts it in rc.local and the instructions say to remove and place it as above. The daemon does not start from rc.local either.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting it in `/etc/rc.d/rc.local`. This worked for me on CentOS with a 3.4.13 kernel.